# Change Exception message in Lazarus

Tags: exception, freepascal, lazarus, delphi

Everytime I use a `raise Exception.create('...');`, it shows, differently from Delphi, the following box:

```
[my message]

Press OK to ignore and risk data corruption.
Press Cancel to kill the program.
```

I just want to change this default message and keep only my part.

Does someone know how can I do it?

Comment: You can assign your own method to Application.OnException, .. or handle the exception if possible... Don't know if there's another way.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Can you show me an example? When I try to associate a handler to my application.onException, Lazarus seems to try to invoke the function and give me an error.

Comment: Let `procedure OnExcept(Sender : TObject; E : Exception);` is a method of a class, for instance of TForm1. Then you can write `Application.OnException := OnExcept;`

Comment: @SertacAkyuz It's very strange. I was doing the same thing you told. But Lazarus gives the error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "OnExcept". And I did it the private declarations too: 
---------------------------------
procedure onExcept(sender: TObject; e: Exception);
---------------------------------
procedure TfrmMain.formCreate(sender: TObject);
begin
    application.onException := onExcept;
end;
---------------------------------
procedure TfrmMain.onExcept(sender: TObject; e: Exception);
begin
//...
end;

Comment: Now I just did: @onExcept; and it compiled.
Accordingly to Lazarus documentation:
Delphi users often confuse this, because Delphi allows it and adds the @ internally. If you prefer the Delphi syntax you can use {$mode Delphi} instead of {$mode ObjFPC}.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, if you want you can answer the question.

Comment: You go ahead please :), if I'd answered I wouldn't even mention about the address operator.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The merit is yours! Thanks to help me with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure my own exception message, I did the following:

In the private declarations of application's main form:

```
procedure onExcept(sender: TObject; e: Exception);
```

In the OnCreate event of the main form:

```
procedure TfrmMain.formCreate(sender: TObject);
begin
    application.onException := @onExcept;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.onExcept(sender: TObject; e: Exception);
begin
    //...
end;
```

It's important to note that the @ operator is required if you're using Lazarus. If I didn't put it, the compiler would consider `onExcept` as a function call. Delphi adds it internally, so you don't have to worry about it.

If you want to change this behavior, use `{$mode Delphi}` instead of `{$mode ObjFPC}` directive.